# Move part of cell values to column names of dataframe

Tags: r

I have the dataframe below:

```
typ0<-c("sd","dff")
typ1<-c("Overworked:5","Overworked:5")
typ2<-c("notpaid:true","notpaid:false")
df<-data.frame(typ0,typ1,typ2)
```

and I want to use as column names whatever exists until the `:` while removing this part from the cells. The new dataframe will be like:

```
    typ0 Overworked notpaid
1   sd          5    true
2  dff          5    true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr` and `tidyr` one way is to get the data in long format, `separate` the data into two columns based on `":"` and get the data in wide format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -typ0) %>%
  separate(value, c("value", "col"), sep = ":") %>%
  select(-name) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = value, values_from = col) %>%
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE)

# A tibble: 2 x 3
#  typ0  Overworked notpaid
#  <chr>      <int> <chr>  
#1 sd             5 true   
#2 dff            5 false
```

---

Using base R, we can do

```
names(df)[-1] <- sub(":.*", "", df[1, -1])
df[-1] <- lapply(df[-1], function(x) sub(".*:", "", x))
```